# when I use the trtexec --onnx=** --saveEngine=** to transfer my onnx to a trt model, I got a warning from TensorRT

Tags: pytorch, tensorrt

My workflow is like: pytorch --> onnx --> trt.
I use torch.onnx.export() function to export my model with a FP16 precision. And then I use the trtexec --onnx=** --saveEngine=** to transfer my onnx file to a trt model,a warning came out like:
**onnx2trt_utils.cpp:366: Your ONNX model has been generated with INT64 weights, while TensorRT does not natively support INT64. Attempting to cast down to INT32.**
I don't know why and does anyone who can help me with this?

I tried what I can to solve this, but seemly noting can work.

Comment: does anyone can help me with this?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inference with explicit batch onnx model,
try:

```
trtexec --explicitBatch --onnx=your_model.onnx
```

https://elinux.org/TensorRT/ONNX#How_to_use_trtexec_to_run_inference_with_dynamic_shape.3F

Answer (score 0):

TensorRT supports the following ONNX data types: DOUBLE, FLOAT32, FLOAT16, INT8, and BOOL
There is limited support for INT64. TensorRT will attempt to cast down INT64 to INT32 clamping values to +-INT_MAX if necessary

follow this link for the the support matrix of ONNX operators in ONNX-TensorRT
https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorrt/blob/main/docs/operators.md